# How to stop the chart from drawing points in chartarea?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I add points to the chart, using

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x,y);
```

Millions of points were added. The chart automatically starts drawing them in the current chartarea. Problem is that, it could take a long time before the program become responsive, and I don't need to see all of them at the beginning.

If I call

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(a, b);
```

right after adding points, it would not work, because the chartview is still empty yet.

So how can I stop the automatically drawing process?

Answer (score 0):

Just some point of views don't know if it can help of if it is possible but
Maybe reduce decrease value of AxisX maximum can speed up,
Turn off AntiAliasing to none at chart1 can give a try otherwise keep it set All,
Maybe being Drawing Paint can be stopped by catch related Pre Post paint or
other event
  and return "handled" after enough needed requested point are drawn
Try reduce number of Value to be used at Points array of Series it self and
  update this Points array when needed with new points

Regards